# Change Date format MM-DD-YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY in macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried using format function as below

let the `startdate = "06-05-2017"`
`End Date = format (startdate," MM/DD/YYYY")`, but it is not getting changed.
`End Date` is still showing as `06-05-2017`. 
Please help me know what is wrong here.

Thanks !!

Comment: Could it be that there is a space between `End Date`?

Answer (score 1):

Excel probably does not recognise the start date as a date, but as text. You need to work out what your system's default date format is. To do that, you can type this in the immediate window:

```
?date
```

The returned result shows in the date format you need to use to assign a value to your start date variable. On my computer I need to use `dd/mm/yyyy`, so for me, this code works:

```
Sub test()
Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As String
startdate = "24/12/2017"
enddate = Format(startdate, "mm/dd/yyy")
Debug.Print enddate ' will show as 12/24/2017
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape your format with '\', if it contains '/'.

`Debug.Print Format(Now, "MM\/dd\/yyyy")`

Output:

`03/25/2021`